# What is the preferred way to import pylab at a function level in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I have written a relatively simple function in python that can be used to plot the time domain history of a data set as well as the frequency domain response of a data set after a fast fourier transform.  In this function I use the command `from pylab import *` to bring in all the necessary functionality.  However, despite successfully creating the plot, I get a warning stating

> import * only allowed at the module level.

So if using the command `from pylab import *` is not the preferred methodology, how do I properly load all the necessary functionality from pylab.  The code is attached below.  Also, is there a way to close the figure after the function is exited, I have tried `plt.close()` which is not recognized for subplots?

```
def Time_Domain_Plot(Directory,Title,X_Label,Y_Label,X_Data,Y_Data):
    # Directory: The path length to the directory where the output file is 
    #            to be stored
    # Title:     The name of the output plot, which should end with .eps or .png
    # X_Label:   The X axis label
    # Y_Label:   The Y axis label
    # X_Data:    X axis data points (usually time at which Yaxis data was acquired
    # Y_Data:    Y axis data points, usually amplitude

    from pylab import *
    from matplotlib import rcParams
    rcParams.update({'figure.autolayout': True})
    Output_Location = Directory.rstrip() + Title.rstrip()
    fig,plt = plt.subplots()
    matplotlib.rc('xtick',labelsize=18)
    matplotlib.rc('ytick',labelsize=18)
    plt.set_xlabel(X_Label,fontsize=18)
    plt.set_ylabel(Y_Label,fontsize=18)
    plt.plot(X_Data,Y_Data,color='red')
    fig.savefig(Output_Location)
    plt.clear()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [matplotlib documentation](http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#matplotlib-pyplot-and-pylab-how-are-they-related):

> `pylab` is a convenience module that bulk imports `matplotlib.pyplot` (for plotting) and `numpy` (for mathematics and working with arrays) in a single name space. Although many examples use `pylab`, it is no longer recommended.

I would recommend not importing `pylab` at all, and instead try using

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

And then prefixing all of your `pyplot` functions with `plt`.

I also noticed that you assign the second return value from `plt.subplots()` to `plt`. You should rename that variable to something like `fft_plot` (for fast fourier transform) to avoid naming conflicts with `pyplot`.

With regards to your other question (about `fig, save fig()`) you're going to need to drop that first `fig` because it's not necessary, and you'll call `savefig()` with `plt.savefig()` because it is a function in the `pyplot` module. So that line will look like

```
plt.savefig(Output_Location)
```

Try something like this:

```
def Time_Domain_Plot(Directory,Title,X_Label,Y_Label,X_Data,Y_Data):
    # Directory: The path length to the directory where the output file is 
    #            to be stored
    # Title:     The name of the output plot, which should end with .eps or .png
    # X_Label:   The X axis label
    # Y_Label:   The Y axis label
    # X_Data:    X axis data points (usually time at which Yaxis data was acquired
    # Y_Data:    Y axis data points, usually amplitude

    import matplotlib
    from matplotlib import rcParams, pyplot as plt

    rcParams.update({'figure.autolayout': True})
    Output_Location = Directory.rstrip() + Title.rstrip()
    fig,fft_plot = plt.subplots()
    matplotlib.rc('xtick',labelsize=18)
    matplotlib.rc('ytick',labelsize=18)
    fft_plot.set_xlabel(X_Label,fontsize=18)
    fft_plot.set_ylabel(Y_Label,fontsize=18)
    plt.plot(X_Data,Y_Data,color='red')
    plt.savefig(Output_Location)
    plt.close()
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  Unfortunately I have already tried that.  Once I import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, the code no longer recognizes the command matplotlib.rc, nor fig, save fig().  If I import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, then how do I get the code to recognize the other commands?

Comment: You also need to `import maplotlib` apparently. I'm updating my answer now

Comment: I will wait for your updated answer.  I also tried to import matplotlib and that the code still does not recognize the command 'savefig'

Comment: @Jon That's because `savefig` is in the `pyplot` module and you need to prefix it with `plt`.

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work wither.  if I use plt.savefig I get a message stating that 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute savefig.  Also, one would think that if I import marplotlib, then there would be no more need for from matplotlib import rcParams, but if I remove that line, then it no longer recognizes rcParams

Comment: @Jon You are clearly struggling with the structure of the `matplotlib` module and probably python modules in general. The big problem is that you override the value for `plt` with the actual plot, leaving yourself with no access to the `pyplot` module. You need to either have `from matplotlib import rcParams` OR if you don't want that and just want to import `matplotlib`, you need to prefix `rcParams` with `matplotlib` like `matplotlib.rcParams`

Comment: Never mind my previous comment, i just deleted it, I saw a minot error that changed everything.  Your posted code did the trick and I appreciate your patience with me.